# Name of this rhythm?

Tags: theory, rhythm

[image]

Is there a name for this rhythm? I usually hear it used as a rhythmic cadence at the end of a metal song, usually at the end of a chorus. Seen it appear lots of times but have never been able to find a name for it.

Comment: What is the time signature?

Comment: It's in 4/4, think "Number of the beast"

Comment: It happens over 2 bars of 4/4. The pulse of the drums changes giving it a different feel. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVnL2FGUSUA for example in the chorus of this song, the pulse of the drums are normal until 2:00 where it changes to this rhythm. To function as a sort of rhythmic cadence.